# jQuery .hover() not completing on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of `<p class="results">` that jQuery is set to display a hidden `<div>` at the `.hover()` event:

```
<p class="results">item1</p>
<p class="results">item2</p>
<p class="results">item3</p>
...
<div id="hidden">My popup here</div>
...
<script>
$(".results").hover(function() {
     $('#hidden').html(function() {
          [...put html here...]
     }).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
     $("#hidden").hide();
})
</script>
```

The problem is that (I assume) since I have a 200ms fade in if the user hovers from item to item quickly then leaves the `<p>` altogether, the second function to hide the `<div>` does not fire. I am pretty sure I need to add some code with the `.stop()` method somewhere in there, but not sure how to implement it. Any ideas?

Comment: "the second function to hide the `<div>` does not fire", that's not true, after `mouseenter` `mouseleave` fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
<p class="results">item1</p>
<p class="results">item2</p>
<p class="results">item3</p>
...
<div id="hidden">My popup here</div>
...
$(".results").hover(function() {
     $('#hidden').html(function() {
          [...put html here...]
     }).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
     $("#hidden").stop().hide(); // <- important bit here
}
```

Comment: Soooo close. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<script>
$(".results").hover(function() {
    $('#hidden').stop().html(function() {
         [...put html here...]
    }).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    $("#hidden").stop().hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about mouseenter, mouseleave?

http://jsfiddle.net/Yxv25/

```
$(".results").on('mouseenter',function() {
 $('#hidden').fadeIn(200);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
 $("#hidden").hide();
})​
```

**EDIT:**

Or setting a timer, http://jsfiddle.net/Yxv25/1/

I was not quite sure which one you needed.